# OpenWall bcrypt library integration

Tags: c, bcrypt

I'm having problems integrating OpenWall bcrypt library in my project, both in linux and on windows.

Here's what I have done:

1. Downloaded the library from https://www.openwall.com/crypt
2. Executed the makefile to generate the .o files
3. Included the files in my compile command line (see bash file below)
4. Added #include "ow-crypt.h" to my source
5. Tried to use the function crypt_gensalt
6. Got a linking error

My bash file used to compile:

```
project_root=/home/ubuntu/lamodal-dev

lws_lib_dir_path=/usr/local/lib
libxml_include_dir_path=/usr/include/libxml2
lws_lib_name=websockets
libxml_lib_name=xml2
sqlite3_lib_name=sqlite3

debug_compile_flags="\
-g \
-Wall \
-Wno-unused-variable \
-Wno-unused-but-set-variable \
-Wno-unused-result"

g++ -pthread -std=c++11 $debug_compile_flags \
-I$libxml_include_dir_path \
-L$lws_lib_dir_path \
$project_root/code/third/openwall/bcrypt/crypt_blowfish.o \
$project_root/code/third/openwall/bcrypt/crypt_gensalt.o \
$project_root/code/third/openwall/bcrypt/wrapper.o \
$project_root/code/third/openwall/bcrypt/x86.o \
../../code/lamodal-dev.cpp \
-l$lws_lib_name \
-l$libxml_lib_name \
-l$sqlite3_lib_name \
-lcrypt \
-o ../../bin/linux/lamodal-dev.run
```

The output:

```
undefined reference to `crypt_gensalt(char const*, unsigned long, char const*, int)'
```

What am I not linking that I should have?

Comment: Can you try adding `-D__GLIBC__ -D_LIBC` to your compile command (i.e. when compiling wrapper.c)?

Comment: Perhaps you need to put the `#include "crypt_gensalt.h"` et al. inside an `extern "C" {` block in your C++ files.

Comment: Ian Abbott is right. `extern "C" { #include "ow-crypt.h" }` fixed the issue. Thanks!